# Garbage value in implicit conversion from expression `wchar_t + wchar_t[]` to std::wstring

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, undefined-behavior

I have come across something weird in Visual Studio C++ 2013 Community Edition which is either a compiler bug or I'm writing invalid code that does compile without warnings.

Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::wstring text;
    wchar_t firstChar = 'A';
    text = firstChar + L"B";
    std::wcout << text << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output to be "AB" but what I get is random garbage.

My question: is the `operator+` between the `wchar_t` and `wchar_t[]` ill-defined, or is this a compiler/library bug?
In the case that it is ill-defined, should the compiler have issued a warning?

---

*Note:* I am not looking for a solution/workaround. Changing `L"B"` to `std::wstring(L"B")` fixes the problem. What I want to know is if I did something wrong or if the compiler did.

*Note 2:* I also get a garbage result in Visual Studio C++ 2010 and an online compiler which supposedly uses g++, and no compilation error, so I'm leaning towards that code being invalid, even though I would expect a compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`firstChar + L"B"` increments the address of the string literal `L"B"` with the promoted value of `firstChar`. It doesn't concatenate the character and the string. This is undefined behavior since `std::basic_string` will try to copy the string until it finds `L'\0'`, which is beyond its original bound.

`std::basic_string` has multiple overloaded operators that allow operations like this to have intuitive behavior, which is why it works in that case.

Comment: I completely missed the fact that it would be a pointer operation first and foremost.  Thanks for unconfusing this for me.